# Ngxs Store snapshot vs selectsnapshot

Tags: typescript, ngxs

What is the difference between snapshot and selectsnapshot in Ngxs Store?

I know how to use the snapshot, it gets the current state value.

`this.oriFormData = this.store.snapshot();`

So when reset, I reset the store like this

`this.store.reset(this.oriFormData);`

can I use selectsnapshot method to select one/mulitple state rather than using the snapshot to get the whole application state?

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever considered using selector, `@Select()`?

```js
@Select(ZooState.pandas) pandas$: Observable<string[]>;
@Select(FoodState.leafs) leafs$: Observable<string[]>;
```

then use some rxjs magic

```js
let pandasAndLeafs;
[pandas$, leafs$].pipe(combineAll()).subscribe(dinner => (pandasAndLeafs = dinner));
console.log(pandasAndLeafs);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use `selectSnapshot` to get the current state value for a specific state using the syntax you would use if doing a regular `select` from the store.

E.g.

`store.selectSnapshot(MyState)` or `store.selectSnapshot(state => state.myState)`

It's also valid to pass a static selector e.g. `store.selectSnapshot(MyState.mySelector)`